# MacOS xcrun not downloading in Command Line Tools and existing solutions not working

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, git

See other Xcrun issues for full details. Basically git isn't working because xcrun doesn't exist in my file path Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun.  I've tried:

1. xcode-select --install
2. downloading Command Line Tools for Xcode 12 straight from apple's website
3. uninstalling and reinstalling git
4. navigating to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ then did a cp /usr/bin/* ./
5. xcode-select --reset

I don't have xcode.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You don’t need Xcode to use the command line tools. What is the actual problem. Maybe edit in what the problem with `git` is - are you following some recipe or have a specific goal or command with a specific error message?

Comment: Your step 4 doesn't seem right at all - it sounds like a bad idea. Please include the output from git. It sounds like a common problem, that is almost always fixed by running xcode-select install, and xcode-select --reset. Have you tried running xcrun manually? (just type xcrun). Perhaps you have never used any of the tools before, and need to manually acknowledge the license agreement.

Comment: @jksoegaard those aren't steps.  Those are just the different things I have tried. Yeah I know number 4 was a bad idea. The git output error I am getting is in intellij.  When I try to create a new project from an existing repository it says "Repository test failed.  Cannot Run Git: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun."  I ran xcrun --show-sdk-path and got /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk.  So I guess the MacOSX.sdk file needs to be moved to the /usr/bin folder?

Comment: @jksoegaard - moving the file didn't work, shocking I know lol.  I have zero idea what's going on lol.

Comment: I know they're just the things, you've tried - it was just a warning not to do that again, as it isn't a good idea. And no, don't move MacOSX.sdk to /usr/bin - not a good idea. In general you shouldn't move stuff around at all to get this working.

Comment: What happened exactly when you ran "xcode-select --install" - please include the output from the command in your answer.

Comment: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install update is the output I got.